# Efficient large dicts of dicts to represent M:M relationships in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a very large dataset - millions of records - that I want to store in Python.  I might be running on 32-bit machines so I want to keep the dataset down in the hundreds-of-MB range and not ballooning much larger than that.

These records - represent a M:M relationship - two IDs (foo and bar) and some simple metadata like timestamps (baz).

Some foo have too nearly all bar in them, and some bar have nearly all foo.  But there are many bar that have almost no foos and many foos that have almost no bar.

If this were a relational database, a M:M relationship would be modelled as a table with a compound key.  You can of course search on either component key individually comfortably.

If you store the rows in a hashtable, however, you need to maintain three hashtables as the compound key is hashed and you can't search on the component keys with it.

If you have some kind of sorted index, you can abuse lexical sorting to iterate the first key in the compound key, and need a second index for the other key; but its less obvious to me what actual data-structure in the standard Python collections this equates to.

I am considering a dict of foo where each value is automatically moved from tuple (a single row) to list (of row tuples) to dict depending on some thresholds, and another dict of bar where each is a single foo, or a list of foo.

Are there more efficient - speedwise and spacewise - ways of doing this?  ***Any kind of numpy for indices or something?***

---

(I want to store them in Python because I am having performance problems with databases - both SQL and NoSQL varieties.  You end up being IPC memcpy and serialisation-bound.  That is another story; however the key point is that I want to move the data into the application rather than get recommendations to move it out of the application ;) )

Comment: I think you really need to read all the way to the bottom of the question ;D

Comment: If you truly have that many relationships there's really no getting around it. With a better description of the problem there could be some more concrete solutions. NB: Does "nearly all" mean 3999999 out of 4000000 or say, 1M of 4M?

Comment: I read all except for the fine print :)

Comment: Sounds like a sparse matrix.  You might be intereseted in scipy.sparse or PySparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSQL systems like redis don't provide MM tables.

In the end, a python dict keyed by pairs holding the values, and a dict of the set of pairings for each term was the best I could come up with.

```
class MM:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = {} # Bs for each A
        self._b = {} # As for each B
        self._ab = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a NoSQL database that runs in memory such at [Redis](http://redis.io/)? Redis supports a decent amount of familiar data structures.

I realize you don't want to move outside of the application, but not reinventing the wheel can save time and quite frankly it may be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to query the data in a flexible way, and maintain various relationships, I would suggest looking further into using a database, of which there are many options. How about using an in-memory databse, like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (using ":memory:" as the file)? You're not really moving the data "outside" of your program, and you will have much more flexibility than with multi-layered dicts.

Redis is also an interesting alternative, as it has other data-structures to play with, rather than using a relational model with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds like a sparse matrix, where the foos are along one axis and the bars along the other one.  Each non-empty cell represents a relationship between one foo and one bar, and contains the "simple metadata" you describe.

There are efficient sparse matrix packages for Python (scipy.sparse, PySparse) you should look at.  I found these two just by Googling "python sparse matrix".

As to using a database, you claim that you've had performance problems.  I'd like to suggest that you may not have chosen an optimal representation, but without more details on what your access patterns look like, and what database schema you used, it's awfully hard for anybody to contribute useful help.  You might consider editing your post to provide more information.